# How helpful is it for PhD admissions to be second author of a paper in a recognised journal?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I recently submitted a paper to a fairly well-known journal and it got accepted. I'm listed as the second author. I'm a master's student. How much prestige is associated with this if I apply for a PhD?

Comment: There is no measurement unit of prestige.

Comment: It will depend to some extent on authorship norms in your field. For instance, in my field (pure math), being second carries exactly as much prestige as being first author, since authors are typically listed alphabetically.

Comment: _How much prestige is associated with this if I apply for a PhD?_ — Exactly 147 micronobels.

Comment: @JeffE How did you arrive at an exact figure, the empirical tests I conducted gave me ≈ 146.4829 micronobels.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're an experimentalist.  I'm a theoretician.

Answer (score 6):

This is a normal and expected thing for graduate students to do.  You should definitely list it on your CV and make it visible in your application to PhD programs and it will be a positive factor.